# Convert timefield to 24hours in django

Tags: django

I have a field 
Time = models.Timefield

Which gives output as for example 8:30 am
But I want 08:30:00 how can I get it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ time }}
{{ time.start}} {{time.end}} # this prints as 8:30 am but I need 08:30:00

 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Is that in the template or in python code?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have as well

Comment: In template i am getting these values from the model

Comment: Check my answer the last one below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the to format your datetime in your template like so,

```
{{ my_time.time|date:"G:i:s" }}
```

As referenced by the django docs right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily customize the way your date looks/is stored using the input_formats parameter. All you have to do is TimeField(input_formats=(your time format)), where your time format is in the form shown here. For 24 hour time, just do TimeField(input_formats=(“%H:%i”)) or 
you can add the TIME_INPUT_FORMATS to your settings file. For example, TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%i ',).

Comment: it is not allowed in models.TimeField as I am using django 2.0

Comment: you can add the TIME_INPUT_FORMATS to your settings file. For example, TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%i ',)